# linker error with ShareKit ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, sharekit, sdwebimage

i have spent 3 days for searching the solution. I don't know what to do with this... I need the -ObjC flag for SDWebImage library ( and AFNetworking too, i think) . I can remove it, and everything is fine with ShareKit, but not fine with SDwebImage.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions", referenced from:
      +[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:] in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookGetPersonCount", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion", referenced from:
      +[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:] in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABMultiValueGetCount", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABPersonHasImageData", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ABRecordCopyValue", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook", referenced from:
      -[SHKiOSFacebook accountTypeIdentifier] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierSinaWeibo", referenced from:
      -[SHKSinaWeibo accountTypeIdentifier] in libShareKit.a(SHKSinaWeibo.o)
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
      -[SHKiOSTwitter accountTypeIdentifier] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSTwitter.o)
  "_ACFacebookAppIdKey", referenced from:
      -[SHKiOSFacebook authorizationFormShow] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceEveryone", referenced from:
      -[SHKiOSFacebook authorizationFormShow] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
  "_ACFacebookAudienceKey", referenced from:
      -[SHKiOSFacebook authorizationFormShow] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
  "_ACFacebookPermissionsKey", referenced from:
      -[SHKiOSFacebook authorizationFormShow] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
  "_AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey", referenced from:
      -[SHKFile getDuration] in libShareKit.a(SHKFile.o)
  "_CMTimeGetSeconds", referenced from:
      -[SHKFile getDuration] in libShareKit.a(SHKFile.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey", referenced from:
      -[GPPMediaPreviewView thumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:] in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o)
  "_MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
      -[GPPMediaPreviewView initWithFrame:mediaAttachment:] in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o)
      -[GPPMediaPreviewView thumbnailImageRequestDidFinish:] in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
      objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSSharer.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(NSData+GPPAdditions.o)
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(UIDevice+GPPAdditions.o)
      objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(SHKPhotoAlbum.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVURLAsset", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(SHKFile.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(UIDevice+GPPAdditions.o)
      objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(SHKFoursquareV2VenuesForm.o)
      objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(SHKFoursquareV2.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSpamSignal.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPMediaPreviewView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(EvernoteSession.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSSharer.o)
      objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(SHKSinaWeibo.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
      objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSTwitter.o)
  "_SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier", referenced from:
      -[EvernoteSession installAppWithId:withViewController:] in libShareKit.a(EvernoteSession.o)
  "_SLServiceTypeFacebook", referenced from:
      -[SHKiOSFacebook serviceTypeIdentifier] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
      -[SHKiOSFacebook sendFeed] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
      -[SHKiOSFacebook sendPhoto] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
      -[SHKiOSFacebook sendVideo] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
      -[SHKiOSFacebook fetchUserInfo] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSFacebook.o)
  "_SLServiceTypeSinaWeibo", referenced from:
      +[SHKSinaWeibo canShare] in libShareKit.a(SHKSinaWeibo.o)
      -[SHKSinaWeibo share] in libShareKit.a(SHKSinaWeibo.o)
  "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      -[SHKiOSTwitter serviceTypeIdentifier] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSTwitter.o)
      -[SHKiOSTwitter sendStatusViaTwitter:mimeType:filename:] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSTwitter.o)
      -[SHKiOSTwitter sendDataViaYFrog:mimeType:filename:] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSTwitter.o)
      -[SHKiOSTwitter fetchUserInfo] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSTwitter.o)
      -[SHKiOSTwitter downloadAPIConfiguration] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSTwitter.o)
      -[SHKiOSTwitter authorizationYFrogHeader] in libShareKit.a(SHKiOSTwitter.o)
  "_kABPersonEmailProperty", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_kABPersonFirstNameProperty", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_kABPersonLastNameProperty", referenced from:
      ___48+[GPPAddressBook loadDeviceContactsWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GooglePlus(GPPAddressBook.o)
  "_kCLLocationAccuracyBest", referenced from:
      -[SHKFoursquareV2VenuesForm startMonitoringLocation] in libShareKit.a(SHKFoursquareV2VenuesForm.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Add all of the other frameworks that contain these missing symbols.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looks like you are missing quite a few frameworks. According to the symbols mentioned, add following list of frameworks to resolve the linker errors,

- AddressBook.framework
- AVFoundation.framework
- CoreMedia.framework
- MediaPlayer.framework
- Accounts.framework
- AssetsLibrary.framework
- CoreLocation.framework
- CoreMotion.framework
- StoreKit.framework
- Social.framework

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

perhaps,just add these framework

- AddressBook.framework
- MediaPlayer.framework
- AssetsLibrary.framework
- CoreMotion.framework

Comment: i was getting _OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from: error and didn't know how to fix it, This error occured when i updated parse and bolts framework, and i think bolt is using "CMMotionManager". i added core motion and it works. Thanks\

Comment: Mine got resolved after importing `CoreMotion` framework! Thanks :)