# iOs Parse Starter Kit

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push

I'm starting a new application on iOs with Parse. I downladed the Starter Kit this morning, following the Quick Start Guide they have, in order to try the push notifications. 
But without doing anything I got 6 errors. They weren't here the first time I develloped an app with parse, it worked all fine, and now, without doing anything new I got these, and can't find my answer anywhere..

See the bugs here :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRIXq.jpg

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Framework were missing :

This : [linker error with ShareKit ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164753/linker-error-with-sharekit-ios)

List :

- AddressBook.framework
- AVFoundation.framework
- CoreMedia.framework
- MediaPlayer.framework
- Accounts.framework
- AssetsLibrary.framework
- CoreLocation.framework
- CoreMotion.framework
- StoreKit.framework
- Social.framework

And the this : 
[Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS5.1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899920/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios5-1)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've not set up your build settings OR build phases properly.

Are you using cocoapods? If so click on your Pods project in the project navigator, go to the build settings tab and check that it is building for 'iOS' (as opposed to OSX) in the Supported Platforms row and building for Standard Architectures.

If you're not using cocoapods,  Go to your project and check the same. Then in your target go to Build Phases and make sure the relevant libraries (Twitter, AccountStore etc) are being linked to

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Social Framework to your project. Here is a small tutorial from Twitter:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/adding-social-framework

Comment: Works fine, got somme other issues, fixed.